# EEPlus .Net library culture info and encoding

Tags: c#, excel

I am using EEPlus library to manage excel transactions. I suffered from local alphabetical characters in excel.

`2023 Aral&#x131;k Ay&#x131` which ı tried to wrote `Aralık Ayı`

I tried

```
ExcelTextFormatBase excelTextFormatBase = new ExcelTextFormat();
excelTextFormatBase.Culture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
excelTextFormatBase.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
```

Did not work.

Comment: Are you talking about the [**EPPlus**](https://www.epplussoftware.com/) library (not "EEPlus") ??